# Redirection & Google Issue

Tags: redirect, seo, dns, traffic

I recently set my preferred domain from non-www to "www" to prevent duplicate content in search engines. I thought it would be a good thing to choose one and stick with it. I also had to set some 301 redirects because I changed some slugs in my pages to improve my rankings.

My website is http://www.ffmages.com and Google currently indexes it without the "www".

Now, when some of my pages are viewed through Google's images directory, I get a message like this:

> The previous page is sending you to
>   http://ffmages.com/final-fantasy-xii...-etros-shrine/.
>
> If you do not want to visit that page, you can return to the previous
>   page.

I've noticed this has been reducing my traffic substantially because it stops the user from viewing the page automatically. I was wondering if someone could explain to me what would be causing this, and if there was something I have done programming-wise.

- What can I do (if anything) to remedy the Google issue?
- What else could be causing my big decrease in traffic and Google search results?
- Is there anything I can do from the back-end?

Comment: Could you provide details on a specific example. The message shows a link to a missing page (hence the message) indicating you have a problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set canonical link

using this

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/" />
```

change example.com to your link and google will recognize your www.

You can also use .htaccess to redirect wildcard to with www.

The first 1 which is canonical will works better.

I been doing website for 3 years and have PR 4 for most of my sites, i use canonical and the index works well. I also rank fairly well in Google with about 100,000 visits daily for my sites.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure if I understand this 100%. I'm using WordPress, so do I just edit the header once, or does each page need a seperate canonical link?

Answer (score 0):

Google is still changing its index, make a "site:ffmages.com" search in google (web and image search), you will see www and no-www versions of the pages indexed. I've checked the pages, you make a 301 redirect which is perfect.

Do not put a rel canonical version of the page, this is useless.
You just have to wait, and maybe, log in Google Webmaster Tools (or create account) and set the preferred domain (configuration > settings).